# Prefill URL field with required URL address in SPS2013 List

Tags: sharepoint-server, url

Team,

My client has a sharepoint list and would like to have -

URL field to be prefilled with required URL address in SPS2013 List

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

For the hyperlink field you won't be able to set the default value through the list settings.

**JS Approach** - Edit the lists' NewForm and add a Script Editor WebPart with JS code to set the value by selecting the hyperlinks' Input DOM element.

**InfoPath** - Edit the list form in InfoPath and configure the default value.

### --Update--

Edit the list, new form form the ribbon and add the script editor webpart, and add the below code to the script editor webpart. Change the parameter of setColumnValue funtion as required.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {  
  var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");         
   columnObj.val(linkVal);  
 }   
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setColumnValue('Link','http://rjesh.com');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Any reference JS code that will work in this case?

Comment: Guys, please help.

Comment: See my updated answer with the JS script.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. On my List page I have set the field value as "Apply". Therefore, adding a script editor with the above code and modifying only the set column value section with the following, would do the job.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {  
  var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");         
   columnObj.val(linkVal);  
 }   
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setColumnValue('Apply','http://rjesh.com');
 });
 </script>

Comment: On a side line, till the time I wait for Rajesh response.
Tried this, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111171/use-calculated-column-to-add-target-blank-at-the-end-of-a-web-field-url

I can add the calculated column, but viewing an existing item does just show the hyperlink,but the entire code inserted in calculated column.

Comment: Jason, you need to add it to list's default new form. The script looks good.

Comment: Rajesh, just confirming editing the list page from apd2013 n adding the javascript code. Does it has to b place in header or doesnt matter anywhere in the body.

Comment: Rajesh, can you suggest if the code to be added to default new form as part of the script editor webpart? if what is the value in the code that I should modify to set the value set for my column name?

Comment: setColumnName method the first argument is your column title and the second argument is the value for that column

Comment: I`ve added the code via a script editor webpart to the newfor,.aspx and even to allviews.aspx file. but cant see the difference.

Comment: I `ve tried adding the code in a script editor on the New form and display form page, but still the "Apply now" doesn't seems to have the associated url mapped.

Comment: can you please respond as per convenience. As I`m waiting for a solution.