# Is there any way to create a dynamic link in the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

I need to create a dynamic link in the SharePoint list. I have tried with calculated columns.
[image]

But it is rendering as

[image]

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I guess you are referring https://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/ if yes then there is already solution provided here..

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111171/use-calculated-column-to-add-target-blank-at-the-end-of-a-web-field-url/111194#111194

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/sharepoint-online-calculated-column-with-html-not/604ba449-4c2c-4227-b65d-15cac5bed328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try JSLink using this code:

```
var ccContext = {
  Templates: {
    Fields: {
      "Calculated": {"View": "<#=STSHtmlDecode(ctx.CurrentItem.Calculated)#>"}
    }
  }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ccContext);
```

Source an full explanation here: [HTML Calculated Column + Client-Side Rendering](https://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/html-calculated-column-client-side-rendering/)

Answer (score 0):

Just select `The data type returned from this formula is:` Date and Time